# Debian Security Repos missing an OpenSSL Package

Tags: debian, docker, openssl, apt

I tried to build a Docker image and found that an OpenSSL related package is missing and apt is unable to correct the issue. This results in the image being unable to build. It seems like this is an issue with the Debian security repo. Thoughts?

**Docker File:** https://git.ulayer.net/snippets/44/raw

**Error Output:** https://git.ulayer.net/snippets/43/raw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The downloaded package lists are outdated. Your system knows about openssl version  1.1.1d-0+deb10u1, however recently 1.1.1d-0+deb10u2 was released which supercedes the old version.

You need you update the lists; even though your docker file has `apt-get update`, the output shows `Using cache` which is not useful in this case. Of course it's using a cached image in this case, not the cached apt info (although the cached image contains apt info).

It's probably easiest to combine the two steps `apt-get update` and `apt-get install ...`:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openvpn git netcat ca-certificates inetutils-ping curl wget dnsutils postgresql-client mariadb-client libssl-dev libxml2-dev libyaml-dev libgmp-dev libreadline-dev libz-dev libsqlite3-dev libpq-dev libmariadb-dev pkg-config libpcre3-dev libevent-dev build-essential sudo iptables htop procps apt-utils --fix-missing
```

This will prevent an image with outdated (or mismatched, if you prefer that term) apt data being cached.

Comment: I did not think about the image caching. Thank you for pointing this out :)